# Which one is the original prefix: con-, com-, or cor-?

Tags: prefixes

Which one is the original prefix: con-, com-, or cor-?   And which ones are variants?

Answer (score 5):

[Con-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/con-) derives from the Latin prefix [con-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/con-#Latin), which was in turn derived from the Latin word cum "with".

The prefix was assimilated to a following sound according to the following rules:

- Before *vowels* and *h*, the prefix becomes **co-**.
- Before *b*, *m* and *p*, the prefix becomes **com-**.
- Before *l*, the prefix becomes **col-**.
- Before *r*, the prefix becomes **cor-**.
- Before *n* or *gn*, the prefix becomes **cō-** (or **con-** in Late Latin).
- Before *gn*, the prefix becomes **co-**.
- Before *s* or *f*, the vowel in the prefix becomes nasalized **con-** [kõ]ː

Comment: Isn't it simpler to consider 'com-' as the 'original'? (since it started off as 'cum-')

Comment: @Mitch You may have a point there, especially since *cum* itself comes from O Lat. *com*. But traditionally, *con-* is considered (ahem) the unmarked form.

Comment: According to American Heritage Dictionary, it came from 'kom': https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=com-

Comment: It has a nasal at the end, and nasals assimilate, whether they're marked that way or not. So there's no difference between an "original" _con-_ and a _com-_;  both occurred plenty.